# Angular-google-area-chart chart background color overlapping

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-visualization

[image]

I am creating an area chart using `angular-google-chart`. I am trying to show different colors for the particular area.  But you can see the area of red and green lines(areas) are overlapped by the blue area.
Is there something wrong with configuration?

```
"data": {
    "cols": [{
        "id": "date",
        "label": "Date",
        "type": "string",
        "p": {}
    }, {
        "id": 'sd0',
        "label": 'sdo',
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
    }, {
        "id": 'sd1',
        "label": 'sd1',
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
    }, {
        "id": 'sd2',
        "label": 'sd2',
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
    }, {
        "id": 'sd3',
        "label": 'sd3',
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
    }, {
        "id": 'sd1Neg',
        "label": 'sd1Neg',
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
    }, {
        "id": 'sd2Neg',
        "label": 'sd2Neg',
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
    }, {
        "id": 'sd3Neg',
        "label": 'sd3Neg',
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
    }],
    "rows": $scope.dataMap
},
"options": {
    "isStacked": "false",
    'displayAnnotations': true,
    'legend': {
        'position': 'bottom'
    },

    "fill": 20,
    "displayExactValues": true,
    "vAxis": {
        "title": 'Weight'
    },
    "hAxis": {
        "title": "Age",
        "slantedText": false,
        /* Enable slantedText for horizontal axis */
        // "slantedTextAngle": 90
    },
    'chartArea': {
        'width': '82%',
        'height': '70%',
        'top': '15%',
        'left': '15%',
        'right': '3%',
        'bottom': '30%'
    },
    'pointSize': 2,
    'annotation': {
        'alwaysOutside': true,
        'textStyle': {
            'fontSize': 17,
            'auraColor': '#eee',
            'annotationsWidth': 25,
            'color': '#eee'
        }
    },
    'series': {
        0: { areaOpacity: 1},
        1: { areaOpacity: 1},
        2: { areaOpacity: 1},
        3: { areaOpacity: 1},
        4: { areaOpacity: 1},
        5: { areaOpacity: 1},
        6: { areaOpacity: 1}
    },
    'colors': ['#FF0000','#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF','#00FF00','#0000FF','#FFFFFF']
},
```

In `$scope.dataMap` I am pushing data from arrays:

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.sd0.length;i++){
    $scope.dataMap.push({
        c: [{
            v: $scope.gData.sd0[i].month
        }, {
            v: $scope.gData.sd0[i].value
        }, {
            v: $scope.gData.sd1[i].value
        }, {
            v: $scope.gData.sd2[i].value
        }, {
            v: $scope.gData.sd3[i].value
        }, {
            v: $scope.gData.sd1Neg[i].value
        }, {
            v: $scope.gData.sd2Neg[i].value
        }, {
            v: $scope.gData.sd3Neg[i].value
        }]
    });
}
```

`$scope.gData` is object I am getting from post request and contains value arrays. There are 7 value arrays, JSON structure is same for all

```
"sd0": [
    {
        "month": "0",
        "value": "2.1"
    },
    {
        "month": "1",
        "value": "2.9"
    },
    {
        "month": "2",
        "value": "3.8"
    },
    {
        "month": "3",
        "value": "4.4"
    }
    .....
]
```

Comment: I want a unique color for particular chart area, the charts plotted in above image is in order sd3,sd2,sd1,sd0,sd1neg,sd2neg,sd3neg and the color codes in colors array are in order with `data` defined in code which is sd0,sd1,sd2,sd3,sd1neg,sd2neg,sd3neg.

Comment: in the colors array, you have 3 colors that are used twice each, with the last being white -- if you want unique colors, need to use 7 different colors, and does the white series even show? -- just trying to understand if the color use is intentional, or part of the problem...

Comment: i am trying to achieve something like this, https://www.bcm.edu/bodycomplab/Images/Flash/BMIexpl.png

Comment: highlighting the area between two specific values, according to that i am using colors in area chart.

Comment: can you put your code to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
**HTML**
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>


**js**

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2013',  1000,      400],
      ['2014',  1170,      460],
      ['2015',  660,       1120],
      ['2016',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2013', 1000, 400],
    ['2014', 1170, 460],
    ['2015', 660, 1120],
    ['2016', 1030, 540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Year',
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```